# Generar un resultado para cada document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, array, dom, object

Tengo el siguiente código js que hace lo siguiente:

Muestra de manera ordenada lo que recupera de un arreglo en un select
pero no se como hacer que imprima en el  si el producto seleccionado es solido o liquido.. me he bloqueado, y por ello recurro a su colaboración. Dejo sólo el codigo JS.

Vale acotar que ya intente colocando `document.getElementById("tipo").innerHTML = tipo;` despues de `document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = document.write(text);` pero no funciona.

```js
producto = [
    /*
    a: Abreviacion Formula
    n: Nombre con espacio igual espacio ( = )
    v: valor inicial
    t: tipo de producto true para liq y false para sol
    */
    { c: " ", n: 'Jabon en Pasta', v: 0, t: "sol" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Ambientador', v: 0, t: "liq" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Cloro', v: 0, t: "liq" }
];
producto.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.n > b.n) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.n < b.n) {
        return -1;
    }
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
});
function selector() {
    // document.getElementsByTagName("option").addEventListener("click", location.reload());
    var selec = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("formula").innerHTML = selec;
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "";
    document.getElementById("entrada").value = "";
    document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("procedimiento").innerHTML = "";
}

function salidaproducto() {
    text = "<select class='form-control' id='mySelect' onchange='selector();'>";
    for (li in producto) {
        var tipo = "";
        if (producto[li].t == "liq") { tipo = "Liquido"; } else { tipo = "Solido"; };
        text += "<option>" + producto[li].n + "</option>";
    }
    text += "<option value='' disabled selected hidden>Seleccione un Producto...</option>";
    text += "</select>";
    document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = document.write(text);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres conseguir pero para asignar el código HTML al elemento `lista` te basta con hacer: `document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML = text;`

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con generar un resultado?

Comment: Tal cual como lo tengo el codigo funciona, porque desde el html tengo insertado las funciones salidaproducto(); y selector(); ya que este html muestra una serie de salidas segun la seleccion..!! pero lo que quiero hacer es que dentro de la funcion salidaproducto se genere document.getElementById('tipo').innerHTML = tipo; es decir se genere en el id tipo la palabra solido o liquido. Creo que debe hacerse desde la function salidaproducto() porque es alli donde se selecciona el producto con el cual se va a trabajar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo único que quieres es mostrar en la opción si es "Sólido" o "líquido" no tienes más que añadir el literal al texto de la opción:

```js
producto = [
    /*
    a: Abreviacion Formula
    n: Nombre con espacio igual espacio ( = )
    v: valor inicial
    t: tipo de producto true para liq y false para sol
    */
    { c: " ", n: 'Jabon en Pasta', v: 0, t: "sol" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Ambientador', v: 0, t: "liq" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Cloro', v: 0, t: "liq" }
];

function salidaproducto() {
    text = "<select class='form-control' id='mySelect' onchange='selector();'>";
    for (li in producto) {
        var tipo = "";
        if (producto[li].t == "liq") { tipo = "Liquido"; } else { tipo = "Solido"; };
        text += "<option>" + producto[li].n + " (" + tipo + ")</option>";
    }
    text += "<option value='' disabled selected hidden>Seleccione un Producto...</option>";
    text += "</select>";
    document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = text;
}

salidaproducto();
```

```html
<div id="lista"></div>
```

Como puedes ver también he cambiado la forma de asignar el código HTML al elemento `lista`, estableciendo directamente el valor de `text` a la propiedad `innerHTML`.

En cualquier caso yo te recomendaría crear los elementos HTML con `createElement` y utilizar los métodos del DOM para añadir los elementos a éste:

```js
producto = [
    /*
    a: Abreviacion Formula
    n: Nombre con espacio igual espacio ( = )
    v: valor inicial
    t: tipo de producto true para liq y false para sol
    */
    { c: " ", n: 'Jabon en Pasta', v: 0, t: "sol" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Ambientador', v: 0, t: "liq" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Cloro', v: 0, t: "liq" }
];

function salidaproducto() {
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.id = 'mySelect';
  select.classList.add('form-control');
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.disabled = true;
  option.selected = true;
  option.textContent = 'Seleccione un Producto...';
  select.appendChild(option);
  for (li in producto){
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = producto[li].n +
      ' (' + (producto[li].t === 'liq' ? 'Líquido' : 'Sólido') + ')';
      select.appendChild(option);
  }
  document.getElementById('lista').appendChild(select);
}

salidaproducto();
```

```html
<div id="lista"></div>
```

Si únicamente quieres mostrar en el `select` el nombre y mostrar el tipo del elemento seleccionado en otro sitio deberías utilizar el `value` del `option` para identificar el elemento seleccionado. El tipo puedes obtenerlo del elemento correspondiente del array `producto`:

```js
var producto = [
    /*
    a: Abreviacion Formula
    n: Nombre con espacio igual espacio ( = )
    v: valor inicial
    t: tipo de producto true para liq y false para sol
    */
    { c: " ", n: 'Jabon en Pasta', v: 0, t: "sol" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Ambientador', v: 0, t: "liq" },
    { c: " ", n: 'Cloro', v: 0, t: "liq" }
];

function salidaproducto() {
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.id = 'mySelect';
  select.classList.add('form-control');
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.disabled = true;
  option.selected = true;
  option.textContent = 'Seleccione un Producto...';
  select.appendChild(option);
  for (li in producto){
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = producto[li].n;
    option.value = producto[li].n;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
  select.addEventListener('change', selector);
  document.getElementById('lista').appendChild(select);
}

function selector(){
  var productoSeleccionado = 
    producto.find(x => x.n === this.value);
  var tipoEl = document.getElementById('tipo');
  if (productoSeleccionado){
    tipoEl.innerText = (productoSeleccionado.t === 'liq'
      ? 'Líquido' : 'Sólido');
  }
  else{
    tipoEl.innerText = '';
  }
}

salidaproducto();
```

```css
div{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lista"></div>
<div id="tipo"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tomar parte de su tiempo en contestar mi requerimiento, muy amable de su parte.. Ese codigo me parece mucho mas estructurado, me encanta y lo voy a tratar de implementar..! pero me nace una nueva duda y es de como puedo agregar el onchange='selector();' intente con     select.setAttribute("onchange" = selector());
 pero no funciona, creo que esta malo mi interpretacion..! y lo otro es el lograr que escriba en el <div id="tipo"></div> es decir que solo escriba si es liquido o solido..!

Comment: Para asociar controladores a los eventos lo mejor es utilizar el método `addEventListener`: `select.addEventListener('change', selector);`

Comment: Listo Implementado.. aun me falta extraer Solido y Liquido al <div id="tipo"></div> segun corresponda  la seleccion..!!

Comment: ¿Dónde ? ¿En el método `selector` al seleccionar un valor?

Comment: He implementado el codigo sugerido para `function salidaproducto()` que manda al `<div id="lista"></div>` lo generado en la funcion `salidaproducto();`  si utilizara la linea sugerida `option.textContent = producto[li].n +
      ' (' + (producto[li].t === 'liq' ? 'Líquido' : 'Sólido') + ')';` la salida en el div lista fuera algo como Cloro (LIQUIDO) y lo requerido es que sea como en efecto lo limpie que en el div lista solo muestre Cloro y que en el div tipo muestre LIQUIDO. Sigo leyendo sobre DOM pero nada que logro comprender como debe ser la instruccion que debo indicarle a la function.

Comment: He ampliado el ejemplo de la respuesta para mostrar el tipo en un elemento separado. Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Como pudiera lograr que despues que se seleccione el producto siga quedando `option.textContent` es decir siga apareciendo la palabra Seleccione un Producto, he intentado con `sup = 'Seleccione un Producto...';` y `document.getElementById("mySelect").value = sup;` en la funcion `selector()` pero solo reinicia una sola vez, luego sigue dejando la opcion seleccionada.